# User restricted file access

Tags: php, wordpress, file, directory, restriction

I need to make a restricted file access system in php (I use Wordpress for my site).

Here is my idea:

1. User creates file via a pdf generator
2. Save this file in a specific folder (with a ID)
3. Denie the access for everybody - including the user who generated the file
4. Check on a output.php file if the user is the same who generated the file
5. Give the user the link for the file

The thing is that the file should be just downloadeble from the output.php and not via url in browser or something else. I know that sound unimpossible but is there everybody who has an idea? Although with restrictions if all is not possible.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I think you have to use `.htaccess` to restrict all access to that folder, and with php download it, I never done a download via PHP, so I cant help you there, but I saw it before and is not difficult

Comment: @P0lT10n where did you see it?

Comment: First of all, files should be available in a fake URL and the file should be inaccessible via web. The script do that will depend mainely on two functions `header()` to set content type and `file_get_contents()` to read the file.

Comment: @Johnny97 i read that in other places, but for experience

Comment: @sємsєм Sounds realy complex and I have absolutely no idea from this :D

Comment: we dont take project specs and turn them in to code for you.

Comment: @Johnny97 No No, it is not complex at all. The tool that generates the pdf, should save it in web inaccessible folder, then save its handling data in any mean of data storage, database for example, handling data, should be mainly id, path, owner, etc. then the read script checks the required permissions and simply returns its contents to the granted user.

Comment: @nogad I don't want that!! I just need some informations who helps to build this system! I've researched a lot but I couldn't find enough informations for me to be a little bit more wiser. I am a beginner and not a profi

Comment: well @sємsєм has nicely condensed what you need to do.

Comment: Found this tutorial and I'll test this and post my solution here  http://www.tutorialchip.com/php-download-file-script/